# Why does glVertexAttribPointer without glBindBuffer also work?

Tags: opengl-es

In several OpenGL ES examples, I have seen the following code

```
GL_FLOAT vVertices[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), vVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3, 1);
```

to draw a triangle. (You can easily fill in with simple shaders, the only vertex attributes assume is a vec2 of 2D coordinates.)

From this piece of tutorial code, I tend to believe the last argument to `glVertexAttribPointer` should be the pointer to where the vertex data is located. However, the documentation https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification seems to suggest that it is supposed to be **an integer** but **purposely cast** to a `const void*`.

But why does the code above work? How does OpenGL know when to interpret the argument as pointer and when to interpret as integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But why does the code above work?

Because OpenGL ES still supports the functionality from before desktop OpenGL removed it in 3.2. The wiki describes core desktop OpenGL's functionality.

It should be noted that ES does discourage the practice of using client-side memory for vertex data. But they have to continue "supporting" it due to backwards compatibility.

> How does OpenGL know when to interpret the argument as pointer and when to interpret as integer?

If a buffer object is bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, then the Pointer argument is interpreted as an integer. If no buffer is bound to that binding point, then the Pointer argument must be an actual memory pointer.